# Best practice of overlaying 'Must Sign-in screen'

Tags: ios, swift

What is the best practice of hiding UIViewController (or overlaying it) with screen talking to user about "Sign-In/Sign-Up"?

I want to hide Profile VC, because user must be authenticated first.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should do:

1: Create 2 Viewcontrollers (Profile and Login/register)

2: In app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` look if user is
    signed in, if not point(in my case I declared initialVC) him to login/register screen like this
    maybe:

```
if currentUser != nil{
self.window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController")
}else{
self.window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login/RegisterViewController")
}
```

Comment: Yeah! thank you. But what if I just need to show in only for 'Profile' tab (UITabBarViewController) ?

Comment: You want to load into profile and then check if user is logged in? And if not then pop modal to login?

Comment: something like this, yeap. I think I just need to present signup vc.